# Want to get disabled select field value when form is submitted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have one form and in that one dropdown is in disabled status as per below :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId" class="form-label required"></label>
      <div class="form-group">
         <select class="form-control" asp-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId"
                                    asp-items="Model.ProjectJobList" disabled></select>
      </div>
      <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId"></span>
</div>
```

Now when we submit form then this field's value is not coming as it is in disabled state so.

Any idea how can I get this fields value when we submit form.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Readonly*** Attribute instead of disabled

Comment: if we use readonly then user can select values from select box, I want to make disabled it.

Comment: A disabled textbox will not postback to the server hence you can try using a hidden field to store the value and use it after postback

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use route parameter:

```
<form method="post" asp-route-ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId=@Model.ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId>
   ...
</form>
```

Or you can try to remove `disabled` before form submitting:

```
    <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId" class="form-label required"></label>
          <div class="form-group">
             <select class="form-control" asp-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId"
                                        asp-items="Model.ProjectJobList" disabled></select>
          </div>
          <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId"></span>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
<script>
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
            $("#ItemEditModel_ProjectJobId").removeAttr("disabled");
            return true; // return false to cancel form action
        });
</script>
```

Or you can add a hidden input to bind `ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId`:

```
<form method="post">
      <input hidden asp-for="ItemEditModel.ProjectJobId" />
      ...
</form>
```